# Upgrading MariaDB 10.11 to 11.3

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-11

I run MariaDB 10.11 on different Servers and wanted to upgrade to 11.x for a while but struggle with the upgrade.
I stop MariaDB. Uninstall the old version and install for example 11.3. Then i always get `[ERROR] InnoDB: The change buffer is corrupted`. I can make a dump and import the dump after the upgrade and get all data even with the history (I use System-Versioned Tables). But then my users can login without a password even when in mysql.user there is one.
I encrypted the database with

```
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
loose_file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
loose_file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
loose_file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
innodb_encrypt_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
innodb_encryption_threads = 4
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 1
```

Full Log of the error after the upgrade:

```
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.3.2-MariaDB-1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 068a6819eb63bcb01fdfa037c9bf3bf63c33ee42 as process 115>
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=4096 bytes)
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resetting space id's in the doublewrite buffer
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=658042216301
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The change buffer is corrupted
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Mär 27 09:40:22 ln-VM mariadbd[115137]: 2024-03-27  9:40:22 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I thought I can just install the new version and run `mariadb-upgrade` and everything just works.
If I install 11.3 and import the dump, I can´t run `mariadb-upgrade` because it says, that it is already upgraded.
I tried with different MariaDB versions but that doesn´t seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry your change buffer got corrupted. Fortunately it has now been [removed](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-change-buffering/) and won't cause further problems once you resolve this.

To gain your users in the SQL migration from your earlier version save them and their grants with:

```
mariadb-dump --system=users --insert-ignore > /tmp/users.sql
```

Then import into the upgraded instance. If you use `--replace` to replace existing users you will need to have a new user that wasn't in the original instance of high privileges in order to import the users:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user import_user@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> grant all on *.* to import_user@localhost with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> grant proxy ON ''@'%' to import_user@localhost with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> ^DBye
```

Restart client with import_user and import the users like they where previously;

```
mariadb -u  import_user

MariaDB [(none)]> \. /tmp/users.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)
....

MariaDB [(none)]>  drop user import_user@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
```